# GLFW returning the wrong GL_VERSION

Tags: c++, opengl, version, glfw

In GLFW I'm setting OpenGL context version via:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
```

However when I print it to the console after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` and `glewInit();` via:

```
Log::brightWhite("OpenGL version:\t");
Log::white("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
Log::brightWhite("GLSL version:\t");
Log::white("%s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

I get the following:

[image]

Why is it 4.3 and not 2.0?

Comment: Because 4.3 is a superset of 2.0. If it gave you 4.3 ***core*** then I would be really concerned, because 4.3 core lacks some of the functionality of 2.0. I believe you are implicitly given a 4.3 compatibility profile in this example; usually the driver includes the profile name in the version string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the implementation is free to give you any version it likes, as long it is supporting everything which is in core GL 2.0. You typically will get the highsest supported *compatibilty* profile version of the implementation. There is nothing wrong with that.

Note that forward and backward compatible contexts and profiles were added in later versions, so when requesting a 1.x/2.x context, this is the behavior you should expet. Note that on OSX, GL 3.X an above is only supported in core profile, so you will very likely end up with a 2.1 context there.